# usage of labels argument in sklearn.metrics.f1_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, data-modeling

I am trying to model a dataset with RandomForest Classifier.
My dataset has 3 classes viz. `A, B, C`. `'A'` is the negative class and `'B'` and `'C'` are positive classes.

In GridSearch I wanted to optimize on `F1-score` since the number of samples in all the classes are not evenly distributed and class `'A'` has the highest number of samples.

That is where I wanted to understand the usage of labels argument.
The [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) says:

> **labels : list, optional** The set of labels to include when average !=
>   'binary', and their order if average is None. Labels present in the
>   data can be excluded, for example to calculate a multiclass average
>   ignoring a majority negative class, while labels not present in the
>   data will result in 0 components in a macro average.

I could not understand it properly. Does it mean, In my screnario I should have labels as `labels = ['B', 'C']`, just the positive class?
Kindly Help

```
custom_scoring = make_scorer(f1_score, labels=[???],average='weighted')
clf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced', random_state=args.random_state)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=20, scoring=custom_scoring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your label is unbalanced,  you can use the f1_score as follow:

```
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, labels=['B','C'], average='weighted')
```

Comment: so we should provide the positive class labels in labels argument?

Comment: it depends on your targets. if you expect the model performs well in positive classes, you should do that, if you expect in all classes, you can leave it empty or with all your classes.